# Can't use concrete subclass to implement a property in protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm doing something similar to the Bridge Pattern in JAVA, `DriverType` is a protocol requires a property named `vehicle` to be a `Drivable` object, `Drivable` is also a protocol and is adopted by the class 'Car'

```
protocol Drivable {
    var speed: Double { get }
}

protocol DriverType {
    var vehicle: Drivable { get }
}

class Car: Drivable {
    var speed = 80.0;
    var brand = "BMW"
}

class Driver: DriverType {

    var vehicle: Car = Car() //Error: Type 'Driver' does not conform to protocol 'DriverType'

    // This one works, but I have to downcast the property to 'Car' everytime I use it.
    var vehicle: Drivable = Car() //Type 'Driver' does not conform to protocol 'DriverType'
}
```

When I implement the `Driver` class, it's very natural to declare `vehicle` property as a `Car`. But then I ran into the problem that compiler thinks `Driver` doesn't conform to `DriverType` even though `Car` conforms to `Drivable` perfectly.

UPDATE:

@Antonio 's answer is solid, but this is what I currently settled, it doesn't involve generic with the class.

```
protocol Drivable {
    var speed: Double { get }
    init()
}

protocol DriverType {
    func vehicle() -> Drivable
}

class Car: Drivable {
    var speed = 80.0;
    var brand = "BMW"
    required init() {}
}

class Driver: DriverType {
    private var m_vehicle: Car = Car()
    func vehicle() -> Drivable {
        return m_vehicle
    }

    // Inside Driver class I use the m_vehicle property directly
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as doing this in your original code: `var vehicle: Drivable = Car()`

Comment: No it's not the same. I don't know why Swift treat property and function differently, you can try my edited example in playground.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... but properties and functions *are* different :). By the way, I tried `let vehicle: Drivable = Car()` in playground, as well as your code, and I don't see any difference (besides doing a func call as opposed to reading a property). Maybe there's something else that it's not clear...

Comment: My ultimate goal is implment bridge pattern in Swift. Now I can use `m_vehicle` directly inside `Driver` so I don't have to downcast it every time. Since `m_vehicle` is a `Car` which adopts the `Drivable` protocol, I have no problem returning it in the `vehicle` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compiler error is misleading. `DriverType` states that any class adopting it must expose a `vehicle` property with `Drivable` type, not a property with a class type adopting the `Drivable` type.

I would solve this issue by defining both the `DriverType` protocol and the `Car` class using generics:

```
protocol Drivable {
    var speed: Double { get }
    init()
}

protocol DriverType {
    typealias T: Drivable
    var vehicle: T { get }
}

class Car: Drivable {
    var speed = 80.0;
    var brand = "BMW"
    required init() {}
}

class Driver<T: Drivable>: DriverType {   
    var vehicle: T = T() 
}
```

This explicitly states that classes adopting `DriverType` must expose a `vehicle` property whose type is any class adopting the `Drivable` protocol.

Comment: This answer does work but also has it's limitation, like giving up Objective-C compatibility and can't use swift enum types in `Driver`. Before I can find a perfect solution, I simply change the property vehicle to a function with a backing private stored property.

Comment: I would consider compatibility with objective-c a limitation, because to enable that you have to limit how far you can go with Swift and all the power it has. Generics is one of them. As a general rule, I always try to avoid obj-c compatibility unless strictly needed and if there is no other way to achieve the same using pure swift. My understanding is that obj-c compatibility is important for you in this case, so yes, my solution wouldn't solve your specific case.

Comment: By the way your specific problem may not have a natural solution in OOP. If in a superclass (or protocol) you define a property of a certain type A, in the subclass you cannot declare the same property using a type B inherited from A (or adopting the protocol), because B is different than A - whereas the opposite is almost true.

Comment: Example: if `Car` is a subclass of `Drivable`, you cannot assign an instance of `Drivable` to a variable of type `Car`: `let car: Car = Drivable()` (here I am supposing that `Drivable` is a concrete type and not a protocol, but the same concept applies). You can do the opposite though: `let drivable: Drivable = Car()`

Comment: @Antonio: But in this case it's a read-only property in `DriverType`. So nobody would be able to assign `Drivable()` to it.

Comment: @newacct: just make the prop writable in the protocol: `var vehicle: Drivable { get set }`

Comment: @Antonio: But it isn't writable. If it were writable that would be another question. In Objective-C you can implement a read-only property with a subtype property in a subclass I believe.

Comment: @newacct not sure I caught what you mean - you want to make it readonly in the protocol, but then implement as writable?

Comment: What I mean is, the literal translation of the code in the question to Objective-C, compiles and is safe: `@protocol Drivable
@property (readonly) double speed;
@end

@protocol DriverType
@property (readonly) id<Drivable> vehicle;
@end

@interface Car : NSObject <Drivable>
@property (readwrite) double speed;
@end

@interface Driver : NSObject <DriverType>
@property (readwrite) Car *vehicle;
@end

@implementation Car
@end

@implementation Driver
@end`

Comment: @newacct in swift you can't do that straight away. By the way I consider that unnecessary because it breaks polymorphism. You can pass an object adopting the `DriverType` interface around and use its methods and properties, but if you pass a `DriverType` as if it were a `Driver`, sooner or later you'll have problems because a `Drivable` is not a `Car`, although `Car` can behave as a `Drivable`. Unless you have a hierarchy of class/protocols using these classes and protocols, I consider either `DriverType` or `Driver` unnecessary. However the answer is no, you can't do that in swift