# Swift protocols: Why does the compiler complain that my class doesn't conform to a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

I've been playing around with Swift protocols and I'm trying to figure out why this code isn't working...

```
protocol Animal {
  var name: String {get}
  var breed: String {get}
}

struct Bird: Animal {
  var name: String
  var breed: String
  var wingspan: Double
}

protocol AnimalHouse {
  var myAnimal: Animal! {get set}
}

class Birdhouse: AnimalHouse {
  var myAnimal: Bird!

  func isOpeningBigEnough() -> Bool {
    return myAnimal.wingspan <= 5.0
  }
}
```

The problem the compiler keeps giving me is that that `BirdHouse` doesn't conform to protocol `AnimalHouse`. If you follow up, it'll tell you that `myAnimal` requires type `Animal`, and I'm supplying type `Bird`. Obviously, `Bird` does conform to the `Animal` protocol, but that's not enough to make the compiler happy.

I'm assuming this is one of those one-line fixes where the trick is knowing where the one line is. Anybody have any suggestions?

(And, yes, I could make `myAnimal` an `Animal` and then cast it as a `Bird` later in the function, but that seems unnecessarily messy.)

Comment: I believe the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419529/cant-use-concrete-subclass-to-implement-a-property-in-protocol-in-swift. Unfortunately, it is not all that elegant. Certainly, what you typed should be supported by the compiler.

Comment: @Robert: No, it should not be supported by the compiler. The compiler is right. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself in the question, you can't just downcast to `Bird` from `Animal`. I propose changing the var to be optional, as an `AnimalHouse` is likely to be without inhabitant some of the time.

In my implementation below non `Bird` animals can't enter the birdhouse.

```
protocol AnimalHouse {
    var myAnimal: Animal? {get set}
}

class Birdhouse: AnimalHouse {
    var myAnimal: Animal? {
        get{
            return myBird
        }
        set(newanimal){
            if let bird = newanimal as? Bird {
                myBird = bird
            }
        }
    }

    private var myBird: Bird?

    func isOpeningBigEnough() -> Bool {
        return myBird?.wingspan <= 5.0
    }
}
```

A further development of the `AnimalHouse` protocol might be to add `throws` to the setter ([not possible as of Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32899392/1329214)) or that an `AnimalHouse` returns the type of animal it can house.

```
protocol AnimalHouse {
    var myAnimal: Animal? {get set}
    func houses() -> Any
}

class Birdhouse: AnimalHouse {
    func houses() -> Any {
        return Bird.self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my situation, I realized that I didn't actually need a public setter for myAnimal -- only a getter. So making myAnimal a computed property that grabbed myBird, as you did, basically got my what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is right.

When you write

```
protocol AnimalHouse {
    var myAnimal: Animal! {get set}
}
```

you are making (among the others) the following statement:

> If a type does conform to `AnimalHouse`, then it is possible to put an
>   `Animal!` inside the `myAnimal` property.

Now let's look at how `Birdhouse` is defined

```
class Birdhouse: AnimalHouse {
    var myAnimal: Bird!

    ...
}
```

The type on `myAnimal` is `Bird!`.
And you cannot put an `Animal!` inside a property of type `Bird!`.

So `Birdhouse` does **not** respect what promised in the `AnimalHouse` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will be satisfied with such an approach:

```
protocol Animal {
    var name: String {get}
    var breed: String {get}
}

struct Bird: Animal {
    var name: String
    var breed: String
    var wingspan: Double
}

// Read from here

protocol House {
    typealias Inhabitant
    var inhabitant: Inhabitant! {get set}
}

class Birdhouse: House {
    typealias Inhabitant = Bird
    var inhabitant: Inhabitant!

    func isOpeningBigEnough() -> Bool {
        return inhabitant.wingspan <= 5.0
    }
}
```

But then the 'House' protocol can only be used as a generic constraint, i.e. the following is impossible:

```
let house: House = Birdhouse() // Compile-time error
```

But you can do the following:

```
func printHouseInhabitant<T: House>(house: T) {
    print(house.inhabitant)
}

let house = Birdhouse()
house.inhabitant = Bird(name: "Unnamed", breed: "general bird", wingspan: 4.5)
printHouseInhabitant(house) // "Bird(name: "1", breed: "2", wingspan: 3.0)\n"
```